# In keyword "using" compiler shows error

Tags: c#

```
  using(EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
            {
                return entities.Employees.ToList();
            }
```

Here is the error I get:

> 'EmployeeDataAccess.EmployeeDBEntities':type used in a using statement
>   must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

What is this, I can't understand this error.

Comment: in order to use "using" EmployeeDBEntities must implement IDisposable interface

Comment: What type is `EmployeeDBEntities`? If it doesn't implement `IDisposable`(or any parent type in the inheritance tree) you will get this error if you use the `using`-statement with it

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score -1):

using is for Disposable objects. It looks  like EmployeeDBEntities is not disposable